# Make if statement change where statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

im having a hard time trying to make this query work, what I really want is to have it return sum of my sales grouped by each hour.

problem is as in my earlier questions I need to have my days from 7 to 7 the next day. So here im trying to make query that will return sales for all hours but i'm not that familiar with if statements so what im doing wrong.

if i remove my ifstatement and replace realdate with CURDATE() this query will work for 00:00:00 to 00:00:00

```
  SELECT DATE(delivered) as date, sum(price) as sum, HOUR(delivered) AS hour,
    IF(HOUR(NOW()) < 7, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, CURDATE()) as realdate
          FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable
         WHERE payingcustomerID = 2
           AND delivered >= realdate
           AND delivered <  realdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         GROUP BY DATE(delivered), HOUR(delivered)
```

EDIT1:

as suggested I have tried to make my first SQLFiddle for this question!

[sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f778/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f778/2) here you go
and to futher explain my main problem is that im trying to collect DATA for a graph but in nightclubs they normally do their Z-report/daily report from 7 to 7 the next day. thats why im trying to collect my data in this format.

Comment: I have never tried SQLFiddle but sounds like I should try it rightaway!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f778/2 i tried this! will this help people in anyway?

as you can see here it gives me the same date for the items before 7 in the morning. but i would like to get either those before as the day before or those after. if it makes sense